# How to using code to save plots in Rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there any way to save the plots by code in RStudio?
Like something in Python `save.plt()`.

I have noticed the function `savePlot` can save the figures but I cannot load it in RStudio, since it reports the errors in loading `X11()`.

This leads me to think about another question... What is your way to using R or what is the proper way to using R? As a beginner I found RStudio is super easy to use and I like the idea that saving all the environments into a single file. But apparently it is no need to using `X11()` in plotting...

Comment: depends on what type of format you want. try e.g. `?png`,  `?pdf`, or `?svg` in your console for a variety format options

Comment: @Umaomamaomao if i know the way (the proper code) than format will not be a problem, I can just set as what I want. The problem is I cannot load `savePlot` in RStudio, for the failure in loading `X11()` as it reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plots can be saved as a jpg:

```
jpeg("Name_of_your_plot.jpg") 
# your plot for example    
plot(x,y)
dev.off()
```

Instead of jpg you can choose other image formats such as png, pdf or PostScript. The above code can be modified as:

```
png("Name_of_your_plot.png") 
# your plot for example    
plot(x,y)
dev.off()
```

If you have a `ggplot` you can use `ggsave`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to save from code the plot that is displayed in the RStudio plot tab then you have to call for example

```
rstudioapi::savePlotAsImage("test.png",width=300,height=150)
```